# How to enable python language support in InteliJ while using Docker

Tags: python, docker, intellij-idea, mozilla-deepspeech

I want to use a Docker image and run my python project but when I develop the project I want to get suggestions and support from the IntelliJ IDEA IDE. Even though I could run the project successfully, I cannot get the support from the IDE.

Here I try to print a simple `hello world!` message.

```
Unresolved reference 'print'
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mozilla/deepspeech-train
WORKDIR /speech-to-text-model
COPY ./src .
RUN python transcriber.py
```

1. project structure > modules
   [image: Setting up Python interpreter]
2. IDE does not recognize python statements.

- Here I want to get the python language support, suggestions and etc. How can I configure the IDE in order to accomplish that?
  [image: IDE does not recognize python or does not give any language support]

3. Run/Debug configuration window
   [image: Run/Debug configuration]
4. Running the python project successfully.
   [image: screenshot of the running project output]

Comment: It seems like a known issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-44770 .
Please try the workaround from there.

Comment: @AndreyResler Thank you, that way I could get the python-support.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a known issue - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-44770

As mentioned in the ticket, the workaround is to move all python scripts to a separate module, instead of a facet.